# Error while generating polkadot relay chain specs

Tags: relay-chain

I am using following link to run polkadot relay chain and connect substrate parachain node with it as parachain.

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/

I downloaded the plain chain spece from following link as described in above toturial:

https://docs.substrate.io/assets/tutorials/relay-chain-specs/plain-local-chainspec.json

When I run following command convert plain change config to raw chain config. It gives error:[image]

./target/release/polkadot build-spec --chain plain-local-chainspec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > raw-local-chainspec.json

Error:
0: Other: Error parsing spec file: invalid type: null, expected struct GenesisConfig at line 84 column 34

I tested against following versions of polkadot:
v0.9.29
v0.9.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the plain-local-chainspec.json you got in the tutorial, you can also download its [raw chain specification file](https://docs.substrate.io/assets/tutorials/relay-chain-specs/raw-local-chainspec.json/), so no need to generate it.

From the Polkadot repository where you are trying to generate the chain config, there is already a list of chain specs:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/node/service/chain-specs

So in case you want to run the rococo local:

```
./target/release/polkadot --chain=rococo-local
```

And if you want to get the chain spec file from there:

```
./target/release/polkadot build-spec --chain rococo-local > rococo-chain-spec.json
```